How to make `import` statements to import from another path?
I want to "hack" python's import so that it will first search in the path I specified and fallback to the original if not found.
The traditional way of using sys.path will not work if there is a __init__.py, see below.

CASE 1: The following works:
Files:
.
├── a
│   ├── b.py       # content: x='x'
│   └── c.py       # content: y='y'
├── hack
│   └── a
│       └── b.py   # content: x='hacked'
└── test.py        # content: see below

# test.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'hack') # insert the hack path

from a.b import x
from a.c import y

print(x, y)

Running test.py gives hacked y as desired, where x is hacked :)

CASE 2: However, if there is a __init__.py in a, it will not work.
Files:
.
├── a
│   ├── b.py
│   ├── c.py
│   └── __init__.py # <- NOTE THIS
├── hack
│   └── a
│       └── b.py
└── test.py

Running test.py gives x y, where x is not hacked :(

CASE 3: To fix case 2, I tried adding __init__.py to the hack path, but this disables the fallback behavior.
Files:
.
├── a
│   ├── b.py
│   ├── c.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── hack
│   └── a
│       ├── b.py
│       └── __init__.py # <- NOTE THIS
└── test.py

Running test.py raises the following error as there is no c.py in the hack path and it fails to fallback to the original path.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.c'


My question is, how to make case 2 work?
Additional background:
The above cases are just simplified examples. In the real situation,

Both a and hack/a are large repos with many subfolders and files.

The imported modules (e.g. a.b) may also contain import statements that need to be hacked.


Therefore, ideally the solution would be to only add a few lines of code at the top of test.py rather than modifying exisiting code.
UPDATE: I have come up with a solution below (I cannot accept my own answer in 2 days). If you have better solutions or suggestions, please feel free to discuss.

Are you trying to use mocks during unit tests?

@mkrieger1 No. I am using code from another repo, and I want to make changes without changing the files in that repo.

You can monkey-patch a.b.x at runtime instead of creating an altered a/b.py.

@blhsing Actually the real situation is more complicated. The folder a contains many subfolders and files and I want to hack a subset of them, which will be too tedious to patch one by one.

@JohnAo You can try to overwrite the builtin __import__. If you do you have much more control about the import behaviour. Please note that you might encounter some issues if you consider relative imports. You should experiment with it as well. E.g. I used that technique to unittest a project with optional dependencies.

You should also note that your patch must always be loaded first.

@JohnAo Alternatively, you can pre-load your "hack"-modules manually and insert them with the corresponding import path into sys.modules.

Are you able to include more details in your original question? Your situation seems very specific. It seems that the way you are running the scripts is also relevant.

@lord_haffi I tested that "import and add to sys.module" works. But I have many files under hack. Can I do better than using glob patterns?

The solution is to overwrite the default __import__ function (which is used by import statements) so that it first tries to import from the hack folder.
__import = __import__ # save the original

def _import(name, *a, **b):
    try:
        return __import('hack.'+name, *a, **b)
    except ImportError:
        return __import(name, *a, **b)

__builtins__.__import__ = _import # overwrite with our own


You need to be careful with this solution. If there exists a file called hack/json.py (or any other name that clashes a builtin module or 3rd party module). Then 3rd party libraries will start picking up hack.json instead python's builtin json module. This is because you're modifying how the imports work globally, not just for modules and packages in the two repos you care about.

Instead of modifying sys.path one alternative approach is to use a helper function that tries importing from the given module path prefixed with hack. first before falling back to the actual given path upon an ImportError:
from operator import attrgetter

def import_from(from_path, *names):
    try:
        module = __import__(f'hack.{from_path}', fromlist=names)
    except ImportError:
        module = __import__(from_path, fromlist=names)
    return attrgetter(*names)(module)

x = import_from('a.b', 'x')
y = import_from('a.c', 'y')


I cannot change the import statements. What I want to achieve is to execute a few lines of code and following that no code needs to be changed. Because the modules I import will also import other modules, where I also want the hack to work.
